# Проверка введенных данных

Tags: php

У меня есть код регистрации:

```
<?php
$submit = strip_tags($_POST['submit']);
$username = strip_tags($_POST['username']);
$password = strip_tags($_POST['password']);
$repeatpassword = strip_tags($_POST['repeatpassword']);
$email = strip_tags($_POST['email']);
$date = date("Y-m-d");
$avatarka = $_GET['avatarka'];

if ($submit)
{
 // check for existans
if($username&&$password&&$repeatpassword&&$email&&$startpoke)
{

if ($password==$repeatpassword)
{

//check name
if(strlen($username)>15||strlen($username)<4)
{
echo "Логин должен быть от 4 до 15 символов!";
}
else
{
 //check password
if (strlen($password)>25||strlen($password)<6)
{
echo "Пароль должен быть от 6 до 25 символов";
}
else
{

 //encrypt password
$password =$password;
$repeatpassword =$repeatpassword;

//open database
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$db = mysql_connect("","","")or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("")or die(mysql_error());

// заносим инфу

die ("

Добро пожаловать

");

}

}
}

else
echo "Пароли не совпадают!";

}
else
echo "Введите <b>все</b> поля";

}
?>
```

Я сделал на все проверку, но в шаблоне регистрации есть еще `checkbox`, `avatarka`:

```
<input name='avatarka' type='radio' value='7' class='checkbox' >
```

Как в php-код вставить еще и проверку на ввод аватарки. Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(!empty($avatarka)){
//все ок
}
```

не?

> НО в шаблоне регистрации есть еще
> checkbox, avatarka:

это не checkbox, это radio

Comment: ааа=) я понял спасибо =)

Comment: всегда пожалуйста